Minimize repetitions by removing all occurrences of one number
I did a program in python3 which is correct, it gives the right results, but it has Time Complexity of O(n^2). I wanna improve the Time complexity of this program.
When I run it on a platform algorea  ,the program pass only 63% of tests (only 10 of 16 tests), because some tests take a long time.
could you give me a better and efficient algorithm.
Problem Statement
In a list of integers, a repetition is a pair of equal numbers that are adjacent to each other. For example, in the list 1 3 3 4 2 2 1 1 1, there are four repetitions: the two 3's, then the two 2's, then the two 1's that follow, and finally the two 1's at the end of the list.
You are given a list of integers. Write a program that calculates the minimum number of repetitions that can remain in the list once all occurrences of one of the numbers are removed.
Output
You should output a single number: the minimum number of repetitions that can remain after removing all occurrences of one of the numbers in the list.
Examples
Here is an example of input:
liste = [1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1]

The list of 9 numbers is "1 3 2 2 3 4 4 2 1". It contains two repetitions (the first two 2's and the two 4's):

Removing the 1's leaves the two repetitions;
Removing the 2's brings the 3's together, so we removed one repetition and added one. There are still two repetitions left;
Removing the 3's leaves the two repetitions;
Removing the 4's leaves only one repetition.

If we remove all occurrences of the number 4, only one repetition remains. It is not possible to get fewer than this, so your program should output:
1

Constraints

Time limit: 1000 ms.
Memory limit: 64,000 kb.

The time limit is set so that a solution which iterates a small number of times over the entire list can score full points, but a solution which for each number in the list, loops over all other numbers in the list can only solve about half the tests without exceeding the time limit.
My Solution
liste = [1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1]
# liste = [1,3,3,4,2,2,1,1,1]

repmin=[]
listunique =set(liste)


for x in listunique:
  listWithoutx = []
  for i in liste:
    if i!=x:
      listWithoutx.append(i)
  rep=0
  for j in range(len(listWithoutx)-1):
    if listWithoutx[j]==listWithoutx[j+1]:
      rep+=1
  repmin.append(rep)

print(min(repmin))


How Could I improve the Time Complexity of this problem, like that the program run quickly.
Thanks in advance

What "score" are you referring to?  What makes you think you can improve the Time Complexity (which is not the same as making it faster)?

Where do you test this? Can we test potential solutions there ourselves?

Each Stack Overflow question should be narrowly focused on a specific technical problem in such a way that people who encounter that problem can read and learn from the question's answers even if they're writing a completely different kind of program. If you have a generalized or generalizable question in here, it's not very clear what it is.

@CharlesDuffy How does it differ from for example this question which has over 4000 upvotes?

@nocomment Algorithm questions tend to get closed all the time if they are not super simple (especially when most people cannot think of a faster algorithm). It gets worse if a specific language is tagged.

@Unmitigated Sad. Looks like an abuse of the system.

I disagree that it's abuse -- it's working-as-designed. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/ setting out what SO was intended to be from the very beginning (essentially, a huge FAQ). I couldn't imagine this question or that one making sense in a FAQ. (For that matter, back in the early days we had a "too localized" close reason that was a perfect fit for problems that weren't generalizable to be helpful to others / failed to extract a more widely-applicable underlying issue)

@CharlesDuffy That article was written 13 years ago. And thousands of people declaring that other question as useful shows that it has value. I think this one does, too. And the close-reason looks bogus, this question is easily answerable as-is.

@ScottHunter it's about 63% of tests (My program pass only 10 of 16 tests), because my program take a lot time to resolve the 6 tests

@nocomment, how would a post linked in order to show that current rule interpretation is in line with original intent ("from the beginning") not date back to that original intent? Yes, it's old (and personally written by SO's founder); that's a deliberate element of its relevance.

@CharlesDuffy Who cares about original intent? I care about current intent. And something that old might be just as obsolete as that "too localized".

Linear time (Attempt This Online!):
def min_repetitions(lst):
    total = 0
    remove = dict.fromkeys(lst, 0)
    a = b = None
    for c in lst:
        if c == b:
            total += 1
            remove[c] += 1
        else:
            if c == a:
                remove[b] -= 1
            a = b
            b = c
    return total - max(remove.values())

This keeps track of the last three values without reps as a, b and c, the total count of reps, and for each value, how many reps its removal would remove.
Btw putting it in a function makes variables faster and makes testing easier (you'll see some testing if you click the link).

Thanks a lot , your solution is amazing.

do you know some resources (Youtube, Tutorials, Books ...) to learn how to write an efficient Code, Optimize algorithm with the best Time Complexity?

@MouradBENKDOUR Sites like LeetCode etc might help. But I've been doing this for 25+ years, picked up or came up with things in many different places.

To reduce time complexity you want to do as few iterations as possible. Ideally, iterate over the list just once, and collect all data from one read.
Since you can only eliminate one digit at a time, you can store a few previous values in order to check if a new repetition will be created if the current value is the one that's eliminated.
Consider a program structure in which:

A dictionary is initialized to keep track of repetitions corresponding with each number's elimination (e.g dict["1"] = 2 in your example list, since removing 1s will result in 2 repetitions)
For each processed number in the list, check previous and next values (if they exist) to determine if its elimination will cause a new repetition. If it will, increment the value of the number's key in the dict
Simultaneously keep count of preexisting repetitions in the list and store it as a "total repetitions" value
When you find one of these preexisting repetitions, decrement the counter of the respective number's dict value (since removing this number will therefore remove a repetition)
Once the list is fully iterated through, the dictionary is effectively a record of the net effect on number of repetitions each number's elimination would cause. If dict[4] returned -3, then that means eliminating 4 from the list will reduce the total number of repetitions by 3
Return the number of preexisting repetitions minus the lowest value held in the dictionary

